# How to make alter command take effect In MonetDB?

Tags: sql, ddl, alter, monetdb

I use mclient to connect MonetDB and enter this sql:"alter table t1 rename to t2",then I keep this mclient alive and I use anthor mclient to connect the same MonetDB database, but when I enter this sql :"select *from t2 ",MonetDB reports an error : "no such table "t2"". It seems that only one connection could take effect.So how can I make all connection take effect?

This is Linux OS, actually it is Centos 7.5. MonetDB's version is 2019,April.

In mclient A ,I enter this sql:

```sql
alter table t1 rename to t2;
```

then I keep mclient A alive, I use another mclient B to connect the same database, the I enter this sql:

```sql
select * from t2;
```

then I got an error: no such table t2.
Restart this database could solve this problem.

I expect the output is the data of t2,but the actual output is ERROR,no such table t2.

Answer (score 0):

This error is fixed in the Aug2019 release.